# effective C Preprocessor macros without #define

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, macros

I want use Logger class for logging In C++, this class has static and use like :

```
auto logger = Logger::GetInstance();
logger->Log(message, FileName, Line)
```

for filename and Line number I can use __ FILE__ and __ LINE__ macro but everywhere I use this logger Must be write this macro. **That's My First Problem**

I found a way, that is use #define like this:

```
#define LOG(message) Logger::getInstance()->Log(message, __ FILE__, __ LINE__)
```

and with this function I don't need write this preprocessor.
use #define is **My secound Problem**  as Scott Meyers say in [this](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/C/Addison.Wesley.Effective.CPP.3rd.Edition.May.2005.pdf) book.

Is there any way for avoid from #define and don't write every time this preprocessor?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid the define?  You get all of this mileage out of a single line of code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please refer to book i put in question

Comment: Um, what page are you referring to in the book?  You're not going to force me to rifle through the entire book to try and figure out what the hell you're talking about, are you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey item 2 (Briefly in 38 of pdf and 17 of book)

Comment: OK... So? .....

Comment: is there any way, without define?

Comment: I think you might be taking what the book says there a bit too literally.  Even the book says there are still reasonable cases for using #define.

Comment: This item, "Item 2: Prefer consts, enums, and inlines to #defines." from the book is about using C++ builtin functionality to do what the C language required the Preprocessor to do. However this item is not about using the macro facility to do what macros are all about, namely doing text modification and replacement. C++ templates are a more powerful version of the Preprocessor and can do things like metaprogramming that are difficult or impossible with the Preprocessor. However one thing the Preprocessor was built for is text replacement like you are wanting to do.

Comment: @RichardChambers I'm convinced :)

Comment: The advice in the book is to prefer not to use `#define`s, not to never ever use them. This is an instance where they can be useful.